# simulating a p2p environment on the same machine

Tags: .net, cloud, virtual-machine, p2p, environment

So I'm working on a P2P project and I need a method to run multiple peer softwares in the same machine.

So each peer is identified by its IP address and machine name. I want to run different instances of these apps on the same machine but each of them must have different IP addresses and machine names. Is that possible to simulate such an environment? (I was thinking of VirtualBox but that is just too much as I would need to install lots of instances and run them all simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

Since P2P project may include NAT traversal, the vmware or virtualBox can not support that. I think it's better to use different devices to do the example.